# Changing DNS Records to Point To Server

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange

What I have built is a Windows Server 2003 environment, with Exchange 2003 and a router that has port 25 forwarding to its internal IP address on my network. What I am having problems with is understanding what parts of my GoDaddy DNS to change to get emails to come to my new exchange server, and was wondering if someone could help me understand. What I have in the records are as follows:

A Records:

**Host =** @ 
**PointsTo=** 172.201.0.1

CNAMES:

**e=** email.secureserver.net

**email=** email.secureserver.net

**ftp=** @

**imap=** imap.secureserver.net

**mail=** pop.secureserver.net

**pop=** pop.secureserver.net

**smtp=** smtp.secureserver.net

**www=** @

MX Records:

**Priority=** 10 **Host=** @ **Goes To** mailstore1.secureserver.net

**Priority=** 0 **Host=** @ **Goes To** smtp.secureserver.net

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting mail flowing to your Exchange environment will require setting the MX records to servers that can receive SMTP connections on port TCP/25. The MX records are what foreign mailers use to determine where to forward mail for a specific domain.

---

I'm going to assume you have a single public IP address, and that's 172.201.0.1 as you mentioned in your question.

Your network is configured like this:

```
------------                                      ----------------
| Internet |    ---  [router/firewall]     ---    | Exchange box |
-----------                                      ----------------
```

In order for mail to get to your Exchange box, you have to set your MX record for your domain to be a hostname that any Internet host can get to. The absolute minimum needed would be to set:

**A Records:**
smtp.yourdomain.net = [your public IP address]

**MX Records:**
Priority = 1 
Host = @
Goes To = smtp.yourdomain.net

Unless you have some service as your backup mailer, you will only need one MX record.

Now that the DNS is set up correctly, you need to set up your router to forward port 25 to the Exchange server's internal IP address.

Comment: So do I have to create an A record, say called LOGIN that points to my external IP address, then create a MX record with priority=0 Host=LOGIN, and what does 'Goes To' value be?

Comment: "Goes to" should be any CNAME or A record. The host on that record needs to be able to accept SMTP connections.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting it.

Comment: How do I find out what host will accept SMTP connections?

Comment: @THe Woo I added more information to my answer. Hopefully it has what you want.

Comment: sysadmin,  I think the confusion is the smtp.secureserver.net is GoDaddy's smtp server.  He needs the A Record to point at the public IP address of the Router, and then set the MX to that A record host.

Comment: Host = @ or Host = smtp? for the MX record?

Comment: 'Host' is the domain the MX record belongs to. @ is the short-cut for "current domain". So use "@".

Comment: Also please note: many mail servers will not deliver email to your domain, if the IP address does not resolve to the same name as given in your MX record. Therefore it would be advisable to ask your ISP to set up reverse DNS for that IP address (and if this is not a static IP, then most likely you will have to answer a few tricky questions).